# how to use a for loop to replacing index useing python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Define a function named encrypt which takes as input a string (which is the name of a text file in the current directory). The function should then print the encrypted content of this file.

Here text encryption is done by replacing every occurence of a vowel with its next in the list 'aeiou'. So 'a' is replaced by 'e', 'e' is replaced by 'i', so on and 'u' is replaced by 'a'. Also each consonant is replaced with its next in the list 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz' so 'b' is replaced by 'c', 'c' by 'd' so on and lastly 'z' is replaced by 'b'. The same replacement logic holds for upper case letters. Note that non-alphabetic characters should appear in their original form without modification.

```
def encrypt (eo):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    con = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    for eo in vowel (t[i+1]):
        res=
        return res
```

Comment: Very obviously homework. OP hasn't even bothered to reword the handout

Comment: From above comments I assume I need to read up on the site.  I used Google for assistance and this site came up. I thought it would be a great place for the help. I'm an Engineering major- completely clueless when it comes to writing script as you can tell. I will educate myself on the site- Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code could be useful. Pay attention to the vowel and con content. I appended one letter in each variable vowel and com to avoid the modulo operation. Assume the eo is the input string.

```
 def encrypt (eo):
    vowel = 'aeioua'
    con = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb'
    encrytTable = vowel + con
    res = ""
    for letter in eo:
        res += encrytTable[encrytTable.find(letter)+1]
    return res
```

If eo is the input filename, you need some file read operation like:

```
>>> fh = open(eo)
>>> fh.read()
>>> fh.>>> fh.close()
```

And a more effient way to do it, is pre-compute a encryptTable array and use the table to replace the origianl input in a linear manner. In following code, I assume your input only include lower-case letters. Abd if the shift distance is not 1, you need to modify the code. Pre-compute:

```
>>> vowel = 'aeioua'
>>> con = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb'
>>> encryptTable = []
>>> for i in xrange(97,123):
        temp = chr(i)
            if temp in vowel:
                encryptTable.append(vowel[vowel.find(temp)+1])
            else:
                encryptTable.append(con[con.find(temp)+1])
>>> encryptTable
['e', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'i', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'o', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'u', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'a', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'b']
```

And then replace the content:

```
>>> plain = "helloworld"
>>> encrypted = "".join([encryptTable[ord(i)-ord('a')] for i in plain])
>>> encrypted
'jimmuxusmf'
```

Comment: You probably also need to wrap the index around, using mod or something.

Comment: @Asad Actually do not need. I appended one letter at the end of each vowel and con table.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I left those letters out of this copy.  I have three working copies trying to find the best way to work this. Again, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @user3520307 My great pleasure to see my code be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here:

1. `for eo in ...` would replace the `eo` argument; except
2. `t` isn't defined, so will give a `NameError`;
3. `res=` is a `SyntaxError`; and
4. Even if all of the above was fixed, `return res` will happen on the first character, as it is indented too far.

Instead, you could do the following:

```
def encrypt(eo):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for index, vowel in enumerate(vowels): # iterate through the five vowels
        new_v = vowels[(index + 1) % len(vowels)] # determine replacement
        eo = eo.replace(vowel, new_v) # do replacement
```

You can then do the same thing for the consonants, then `return eo` (which should be indented to the same level as `vowels = ...`!).

Note:

1. the use of `%` to keep the index into `vowels` within the appropriate range; and
2. the use of `enumerate` to get both the character `vowel` from the string `vowels` and its `index` within that string.

Alternatively, and more efficiently:

1. build a `dict`ionary mapping character in to character out;
2. build a `list` of replacement characters using the input `eo` and the `dict`; and
3. `str.join` the output characters together and `return` it.

Comment: If you add a more letter at the end of transferring table, you could avoid the modulo operation %.

Comment: @Sheng that is true, but `%` scales much better to shifts other than 1!

Comment: Yes, it is more general to use %. But we could avoid it by vowel = 'aeiouaeiou'.

Comment: @Sheng but again, that only works for `shift <= 5`, imposing an unnecessary and arbitrary limit (particularly given that there are 21 consonants through which we also want to shift).

Comment: We could use one % operation at the very begining as: shiftDis  = shiftDis % (len(vowels) / 2). With that, we could not to use the % operations so many times.

Comment: @Sheng true, but `%` isn't exactly an expensive operation. I have added a suggestion for a more efficient implementation to my answer.

Comment: I might focus on optimization too much. BTW, an array is enough here. Dic is too much. Letters are in adjacent increasing order.

Comment: @Sheng but the input letters are in arbitrary order, and looking them up in the dictionary to find the replacement is `O(1)` vs the `O(n)` of finding the list index.

Comment: def encrypt(string):
    result = ""
    lowerCon = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    lowerVow = 'aeiou'
    upperCon = lowerCon.upper()
    upperVow = lowerVow.upper()
    for c in string:
        if not c.isalpha():
            result += c
        else:
            if c.islower():
                if c in lowerCon:
                    idx = lowerCon.index(c)+1
                    if idx == len(lowerCon):
                        idx = 0
                    result+=lowerCon[idx]
                else:
                    idx = lowerVow.index(c)+1

Comment: if idx == len(lowerVow):
                        idx = 0
                    result+=lowerVow[idx]
            else:
                if c in upperCon:
                    idx = upperCon.index(c)+1
                    if idx == len(upperCon):
                        idx = 0
                    result+=upperCon[idx]
                else:
                    idx = upperVow.index(c)+1
                    if idx == len(upperVow):
                        idx = 0
                    result+=upperVow[idx]
    return result

Comment: But we do not need to find it in list. We could simply compute the index in O(1). In contrast, with dic, the worst case to find a item is O(n). https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Abigail_I what?! It is hard to read a block of code on comments, if you have a different approach, create a separate answer

Comment: @Sheng how could you find e.g. `vowels.index("u")` in `O(1)`? The dictionary is only `O(n)` when all key hashes collide.

Comment: I appended the method in my answer. Hope it be reasonable. Generally, I pre-compute a list for replacement, rather than finding it everytime.

Comment: @Sheng testing with `timeit` suggests that the dictionary is twice as fast as the list. Python's `dict` is hard to beat, and `ord` and `chr` calls don't come for free! Computing `ord('a')` and `ord('z')` only once each gains a little (only 1.55x not 2x) and removes the magic numbers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forget the cost of ord. If it was coded in C, an array should be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt(s):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    vowelReps = dict(zip(vowels, vowels[1:]+vowels[0]))
    cons = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    consReps = dict(zip(cons, cons[1:]+cons[0]))
    answer = []
    for char in s:
        if char.lower() in vowelReps:
            answer.append(vowelReps[char.lower()]
        else:
            answer.append(consReps[char.lower()]
        if char.isupper():
            answer[-1] = answer[-1].upper()
    return ''.join(answer)
```